# A basket has $10$ green, $10$ blue, and $10$ red balls. In how many ways can $10$ balls be selected from the basket if the number of red balls is odd?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I tried to learn generating functions, but I am a way out of it.
And I know a way to solve problems like that by $S_0 - S_1 + S_2 +\cdots$
Please show me in this way because I don't know GF.

The question is:

> A basket has $10$ green balls, $10$ blues and $10$ reds. In how many ways can $10$ balls be selected from the basket so that the number of red balls is odd?

Here is a picture of what I tried to do and obviously I'm getting negative number of solutions.

[image: attempted_solution]

Comment: Sorry, I see the problem now.  You have already accounted for the red balls, so you should have equations in two variables rather than three.

Comment: I dont follow  @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b$, $g$, and $r$ represent, respectively, the number of blue, green, and red balls that are selected from the basket.  We know that 
$$b + g + r = 10$$
However, we require that $r$ is odd, so there are five cases.

$r = 1$:  Then 
\begin{align*}
b + g + 1 & = 10\\
b + g & = 9
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  The number of solutions of the equation $b + g = 9$ in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{9 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{10}{1} = 10$$

More generally, the number of solutions of the equation
$$b + g = n$$
in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{n + 1}{1} = n + 1$$

$r = 3$:  Then
\begin{align*}
b + g + 3 & = 10\\
b + g & = 7
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $7 + 1 = 8$ solutions.

$r = 5$:  Then
\begin{align*}
b + g + 5 & = 10\\
b + g & = 5
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $5 + 1 = 6$ solutions.

$r = 7$:  Then
\begin{align*}
b + g + 7 & = 10\\
b + g & = 3
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $3 + 1 = 4$ solutions.

$r = 9$:  Then
\begin{align*}
b + g + 9 & = 10\\
b + g & = 1
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $1 + 1 = 2$ solutions.

**Total:**  Since the above cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of ways of selecting $10$ balls from the basket if the number of red balls is odd is 
$$10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 = 30$$

Notice that fixing the value of $r$ reduces the number of variables by $1$, which is where you made your mistake in calculating $S_1$.  Also, the problem asks you calculate what you are calling $S_1$.  There is no need to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle here.

Comment: Why the number of ways of selecting 10 balls from the basket if the number of red balls is odd is
10+8+6+4+2=30 ? what is the sense standing behind it?

Comment: There are five mutually exclusive cases:  $r = 1$, $r = 3$, $r = 5$, $r = 7$, and $r = 9$.  We solve each case, then add the number of outcomes, as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: thanks ive got it

Comment: @N.F.Taussig VERY detailed answer! (+1)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have another question i am stuck on.. if you like to help me it will be wonderful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here there is no need to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (your $S_0 - S_1 + S_2 +\cdots$)

We simply count the number of non-negative integer solutions $(x_1,x_2)$ (with no further constraints) of
$$x_1+x_2=10-x_3=10-(2k-1)\qquad \text{ with $k=1,2,3,4,5$.}$$
They are 
$$\binom{10-(2k-1)+1}{1}=10-(2k-1)+1=10-2k+2=12-2k.$$ 
Hence we have to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=1}^5(12-2k)=10+8+6+4+2=\boxed{30}.$$

Comment: I am looking at all answers and trying to understand. will update you when ive got a conclustion

Comment: Your answer is hardly useless.  I think Lorine had trouble recognizing why we only needed to add the number of blue and green balls once we fixed the number of red balls.  Consequently, your answer may have been too abstract for her.

Comment: First of all, youre helping me a lot!! and last time you helped me and you were really necessary. There's no reason for you to get hurt. I just don't understand the material 100 percent so the second answer is much more helpful to me. You help a lot and keep doing it !!!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I guess that you are right. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to me there is another quite simple way to solve problem is, to consider two basket , one containing 10 red balls and other containing remaining 20 balls. Now we have to select x(odd number between 0 to 10) red balls from first basket and 10-x from second basket, so number of remaining red balls is always odd. 
By using combination formula we get answer: 
$$\binom{10}{1}\binom{20}{9}+\binom{10}{3}\binom{20}{7}+\binom{10}{5}\binom{20}{5}+\binom{10}{7}\binom{20}{3}+\binom{10}{9}\binom{20}{1}.$$
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF0ZA.jpg)

Comment: Your answer is a number much larger than 30...

Comment: Balls of the same color are considered to be indistinguishable, so what matters here is how many balls of each color are selected, not which balls are selected.